# Use of 'it' for a child

Tags: personal-pronouns

Do we use the pronoun 'it' for a kid? Can we say:

> When the child is young, *it* wouldn’t know that it hurts when you touch a hot thing as *it* doesn’t understand hot or cold.

"it" before 'wouldn't' and the one before 'doesn't' refer to "kid".
Are these right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_pronoun#It_and_one_as_gender-neutral_pronouns

Comment: [A Child Called "It"](https://www.enotes.com/topics/a-child-called-it)

Comment: Certainly you can use "it" if you don't like children.  It is rude ... but that's kind of the point.

Comment: Related: *[Is ' The baby is crying because it is hungry' grammatical and natural?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/156171)* and *[Is referring to people as “it” considered rude?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111368)*.

Comment: The accepted answer to the question which this one is selected as a duplicate of doesn't quite paint the whole picture. *It* is indeed an acceptable pronoun for a child in certain situations (and I believe the one described in this question is one such situation). Hopefully people will read past the accepted answer!

Answer (score 4):

For children and pets, *it* can be used if you don't know the gender and have no way to know.

> Look at that puppy, it won't go near the bed.

When referring to children, if there is any way you could have known whether it's a boy or girl, using *it* will seem rude.  For example, don't refer to a child as *it* if you are talking to it's mother and can see the baby - even if you can't tell whether it's a boy or girl.

Comment: Might be worth adding the potential term "they" for when you are wanting to avoid being rude, but don't know the gender (as an alternative to "it").

Answer (score -2):

It's less about grammar and more about acceptance. Some people may consider it rude, some wouldn't.

You can avoid the whole problem by rewording the sentence:

> The young child doesn't understand hot or cold and wouldn't know that it
>   hurts when you touch a hot thing.

Comment: But I see no reason why you'd rephrase the given sentence. How can *it* even be perceived as rude in that sentence/context? I believe that's exactly the type of sentence [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_pronoun#It_and_one_as_gender-neutral_pronouns) talks about where *it* sounds okay. (–1)

Comment: Grammar and opinion of the listener are two different things. Just because you can, doesn't mean someone won't perceive you as being rude, even if that wasn't your intention.

Comment: It's incontrovertible that the sentence at issue is grammatical. I'm talking about how it may be considered rude. Despite the definite article before *child*, I don't think this sentence talks about any child in particular, which means it can therefore refer to **it** as *it* – like I just did.

Comment: @userr2684291 - It seems many people get offended by little things nowadays, whether that allegation of rudeness is justifiable or not. And if someone finds it awkward to refer to a child as "it", I see no harm in offering an alternative phrasing. Just because you wouldn't find it rude doesn't mean nobody else would. Sometimes it's less about grammar and more about emotion. (I don't find the original rude, either; I just don't see it as beyond the realm of possibility.) One could also use the plural: _When children are young, **they** wouldn’t know that it hurts when you touch something hot._

Comment: People take offense at the use of "it" because they see it as dehumanizing. So whether you're talking about a specific child or not isn't relevant since you're still talking about a human.